# How to apply base color to the holes in the picture?

Tags: modeling, blenderkit

[image]

I want to apply a different base color to the holes that I have made through boolean modifier in modelling. But, I don't know how. The holes will have different color.

Comment: just give the cutter object the same object color as your base object before using boolean modifier

Comment: or you can also go into *Edit Mode* and hover over each hole and press `L` to select it and assign a new material to it.